# Con este codigo las 4 ruedas de mi auto reberian girar, y las dos delanteras tambien hacia los lados. Todas giran menos la delantera izquierda

Tags: c#, unity

El codigo se le aplica al auto completo. De ahi, le asigno 4 ruedas y 4 wheel colliders, uno de cada rueda. Todas giran y la delantera derecha dobla hacia los lados como deberia. Sin embargo, la izquierda no hacie ningun movimiento, y solo acompaña al auto cuando se mueve

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

```
public enum Axle
{
    Front,
    Back
}

[System.Serializable]
public struct Wheel
{
    public GameObject model;
    public WheelCollider wheelCollider;
    public Axle axle;
}

[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class CarController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float maxAcceleration = 20f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float turnSensitive = 1.0f;
    [SerializeField]
    private float maxAngle = 45.0f;

    private float inputX, inputY;

    private Rigidbody _rb;

    public List<AxleInfo> axleInfos = new List<AxleInfo>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }



    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        GetInputs();
        Move();
    }

    private void GetInputs()
    {
        inputX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        inputY = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }


    private void Move()
    {
        foreach (AxleInfo info in axleInfos)
        {
            if (info.isBack)
            {
                info.rigtWheel.motorTorque = inputY * maxAcceleration * 500 * Time.deltaTime;
                info.leftWheel.motorTorque = inputY * maxAcceleration * 500 * Time.deltaTime;
            }
            if (info.isFront)
            {
                var _steerAngle = inputX * turnSensitive * maxAngle;
                info.rigtWheel.steerAngle = Mathf.Lerp(info.rigtWheel.steerAngle, _steerAngle, 0.5f);
                info.leftWheel.steerAngle = Mathf.Lerp(info.leftWheel.steerAngle, _steerAngle, 0.5f);
            }

            AnimateWheels(info.rigtWheel, info.visualRightWheel);
            AnimateWheels(info.leftWheel, info.visualLeftWheel);
        }
    }
    private void AnimateWheels(WheelCollider wheelCollider, Transform wheelTransform)
    {
        Quaternion _rot;
        Vector3 _pos;

        Vector3 rotate = Vector3.zero;

        wheelCollider.GetWorldPose(out _pos, out _rot);
        wheelTransform.transform.rotation = _rot;
    }


    [System.Serializable]
    public class AxleInfo
    {
        public WheelCollider rigtWheel;
        public WheelCollider leftWheel;

        public Transform visualRightWheel;
        public Transform visualLeftWheel;

        public bool isBack;
        public bool isFront;
    }
}
```

No es problema de las ruedas ni de los colliders, ya que la delantera izquierda esta IGUAL configurada que la derecha. Ya intente sacarla y reemplazarla duplicando la derecha, pero no sirve. Realmente no creo que sea problema del codigo, pero para sacarme las dudas lo envio aca.